# Can we send Web mail to other(different ) domain using common name?

Tags: ibm-domino, lotus-notes

I have two different internal domains , where i need to send mail from one domain to another domain using Common Name.

conditions:

```
It is from Web, Not from Notes Client.

Reason why I'm using common name is We configured and used the common names for all the employees which we don't want to change
```

For this Can we do anything on server configuration?

I can see different setting in admin client but sure where or what will fix

From Admin Client->server-> Configuration setting ->Router/SMTP -> Address lookup : Fullname Only

Above will do anything for my issue?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.)
Are both Domino domains connected with each other?

http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/7.0/help7_admin.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/c3a0ef3b04981e348525706f0065b9bc?OpenDocument

If they are you can build a route so that emails from jblocks@domain1 are send to tblocks@domain2

2.)
How type the users in Domain1 the name from the user in Domain2? It might be needed to build here a directory assistence:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc%2FDOC%2FH_EXTENDING_NOTES_NAME_LOOKUPS_LDAP_QUERIES_AND_AUTHENTICATION_TO_SECONDARY_DOMINO_DIRECTORIES_2650_STEPS.html